# SSH config file setup with wildcards and DRY

Tags: ssh, config, dry

My requirements are as follows

1. All of our cloud machines need the same config (User, Port, IdentityFile)
2. I need these settings to be applied to them based on domain (*.xyz.com)
3. I also need these settings to be applied when i setup short hosts (See below)

My current SSH config is a

```
Host shortname1?
    Hostname %h.prod.xyz.com

Host test-myname
    Hostname combo.test-myname.xyz.com

Host *.xyz.com
    Hostname %h

Hostname *.xyz.com
    User myuser
    Port 12345
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The exact use cases are 
`ssh shortname1a; ssh shortname1b; ssh test-myname; ssh combo.test-myname.xyz.com`

`Host *.xyz.com` was a recent addition after debugging for the last use case, and this somehow seems to break the first 2.

Is this the right way or is there a neater way?

Comment: I think the "breaking" happened because the `Hostname` cannot be used in the way I am assuming. Only host can be used as a block, and once I added another host between the first and the common, they got disabled.

Comment: This looks very similar to this SuperUser question https://superuser.com/q/469329/148426 with a very good second answer pointing towards CanonicalizeHostname.

Answer (score 12):

On top of figuring out why the config was "breaking", I discovered a new directive `Match`. This lets me do what I intend

```
Host shortname1?
    Hostname %h.prod.xyz.com

Host test-myname
    Hostname combo.test-myname.xyz.com

Host *.xyz.com
    Hostname %h

Match Host *.xyz.com
    User myuser
    Port 12345
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This config does exactly what I need. I needed to use `Host` instead of `Hostname` in the match because it didnt seem to accept `Hostname` but `Host` seems to be exactly what I need.

I was having arbitrary behaviour because I missunderstood that `Hostname` could not be used as I was using before, as a filter or match like statement. It can only be used inside a `Host`, or `Match` and as such, was implicitly below the last `Host` statement.